# Реализация LAG и FIRST_VALUE в MySql

Tags: mysql

Как реализовать LAG и FIRST_VALUE в MySql в старой версии?

Comment: Через подзапросы или через переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAG() over(order by order_field)`:

```
select x, @lag as LagX, @lag:=x
  from ...
 order by order_field
```

Значение поля x сохраняется в переменной и в следующей строке выборки (при заданной сортировке) оно сохранит свое значение до выполнения нового присваивания, т.е. при использовании в предыдущих элементах списка выборки.

Для эмуляции предложения `over(partition by partition_filed)` используется дополнительная переменная для определения момента смены группы.

```
select x, if(@partition=partition_field, @lag, NULL) as LagX,
       @partition:=partition_field, @lag:=x
   ...
  order by parition_filed, order_field
```

`FIRST_VALUE()` реализуется практически таким же if, как и `lag() over(partition by partition_filed)`. Необходимо запоминать новое значение для переменной только в том случае если группа текущей строки не совпадает с группой предыдущей. При сохраняющейся группе переменной присваивается она сама, т.е. ее значение не изменяется:

```
select x, @lag as first_value, @lag:=if(@partition=partition_field, @lag, x),
       @partition:=partition_field
 order by parition_filed, order_field
```