# Mysql - операции над полями View

Tags: mysql, view

Всем привет, недавно начал работу с вью и возник такой вопрос - можно ли производить какие-то операции над расчетными во вью колонками?
Например есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.table(
row_id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
val1 DOUBLE,
val2 DOUBLE);
```

В val1 и val2 инсертятся произвольные данные:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (5, 6);
```

На основе таблички пытаюсь создать вью:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW schema.table_VIEW
AS select
t1.row_id as row_id, 
LAG (val3,1,0) OVER() + t1.val1 - t1.val2 as val3,
from 
schema.table t1
```

и получаю ошибку, что val3 не существует в таблице, что в общем-то логично. Подскажите, можно ли это как-то реализовать? Цель вью - получить колонку val3, в которой будет смотреться значение из этой колонки в прошлой строке и будет добавляться val1 и вычитаться val2 из текущей.

И вопрос номер 2 - если создать в таблице колонку val4, можно ли будет ее динамически апдейтить значениями из val3?

Comment: `Подскажите, можно ли это как-то реализовать` - **Можно** но не так как делаете вы, **заведите переменную и всё получится**.
Вопрос номер два : **Можно**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но могли бы вы расписать подробнее? Не очень понятно как использовать тут переменную.
Вопрос второй - это какая-то функциональность триггеров?

Comment: Переменные, это такие штуки, которые на `@` начинаются. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905194/194569

Comment: А можно чисто оконными функциями. Вам LAG вообще не нужна, `sum(val1 - vla2) over(order by x)` даст примерно то, что вы пытаетесь с помощью lag выразить. Только order by обязателен (как и в случае с lag), когда накапливаете некий итог, порядок строк имеет значение ...

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за ответ! Осталось разобраться, как реализовать сохранение расчетных колонок в таблицу.