# Как отсортировать товар по категориям

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как отсортировать товар по категориям, чтобы товар выводился по очереди по 1 товару из категории, например, у нас есть

Товар   , категория товара

1 товар, категория 1
2 товар, категория 1
3 товар, категория 2
4 товар, категория 2
5 товар, категория 3
6 товар, категория 3

На выходе нужно получить такой вид

1 товар, категория 1
3 товар, категория 2
5 товар, категория 3
2 товар, категория 1
4 товар, категория 2
6 товар, категория 3

То есть мы выводим по 1 товару каждой категории, затем еще раз по 1 товару каждой категории и так, пока не закончатся все товары

Как это можно реализовать? Написание кода за меня не прошу, буду рад любой идеи

Для получения товаров, использую, товаров 100к+

```
Product::whereIn('category_id', [id])->paginate();
```

Comment: Пронумеровать товары в категории `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY something)` и использовать сортировку сперва по полученному номеру, а потом по категории. Если версия MySQL старая и не знает про оконные функции - использовать эмуляцию ROW_NUMBER() на базе переменных.

Comment: @Akina , к сожалению `ROW_NUMBER` не поддерживается, пытаюсь разобраться как сделать на базе переменных. Если я правильно Вас понял, нужно пронумеровать товар для каждой категории? Нашел как пронумеровать весь товар `(@number:=@number + 1) AS num` получаю все по порядку, не получается сбросить `number` для другой категории

Comment: См. например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905194/229437. Суть та же, только в момент смены вместо NULL присваивать единицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina)

Сделал так:

```
DB::select('SELECT id, category_id, @lag:=if(@partition=category_id, @lag+1, 1) as number, @partition:=category_id FROM `products` where category_id in(372,380) order by number ASC');
```

Все работает, выводит товар поочередно, если не правильно сделал, поправьте